# Visual Studio 2017 - Automatically generate methods in code behind from xaml?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

Suppose I have an app with a single page, and that page has ten buttons, each with their own Click="method", where "method" is different for each button. Instead of cursoring over them and hitting F12 every time, is there a command or shortcut that will generate ALL methods in the C# document?

Edit for clarity: In the XAML file, I'm writing

```
<Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Button 1" Click="whatever1" />
<Button x:Name="Button2" Content="Button 2" Click="whatever2" />
<Button x:Name="Button3" Content="Button 3" Click="whatever3" />
<Button x:Name="Button4" Content="Button 4" Click="whatever4" />
<Button x:Name="Button5" Content="Button 5" Click="whatever5" />
```

I'd like a shortcut that inserts

```
whatever1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}

whatever2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}

whatever3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}

whatever4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}

whatever5(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

automatically in the C# code. The control isn't necessarily a button, this is just an example.

Comment: Not directly answering your question but I suggest using [Command Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview) instead

Comment: You know that each controls might have more than a hundred undefined methods right ?

Comment: @Franck Maybe I should be more clear. In the XAML file, I'm defining the method Click="whatever". I'd like whatever(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { } to be automatically generated in the C# code. I'll update the OP.